# How to create a animated button in Phaser 3?

Tags: phaser-framework

First of all, I'm using Phaser 3. I want to create a button out of a spritesheet. When the mouse hovers the button, I want the second frame to appear and disappear when mouse leaves.

```
this.load.spritesheet('button', 'static/img/button.png', {frameWidth: 191, frameHeight: 71})
```

(It's just an image with 2 frames)

I'm stuck cause I can't find any documentation on phaser 3 buttons cause apparently they don't exist. It's all about events on images or text. So what is the aproach here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to create the button as a sprite like this:

```
this.add.sprite(100, 100, 'button').setFrame([frame name/number]).setInteractive();
```

This creates an interactive GameObject with your button as the image. The frame name/number will start out as the first image in your spritesheet. It starts counting frames at 0, so you'll probably go with 0 first.

Then you'll want to use a mouse event like [this example](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src%5Cinput%5Cmouse%5Cover%20and%20out%20events.js) to change the frame on hover.

Something like this:

```
// When hovering
this.input.on('pointerover', function(e, button) {
  button.setFrame(1);
});

// When moves away
this.input.on('pointerout', function(e, button) {
  button.setFrame(0);
});
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply! It seems like a nice way to do that but I tried it and it just loads the entire spritesheet on the canvas and when I hover it, it says on the console that `texture.frame missing: 1`

Comment: @FranciscoRibeiro hmm, sorry to hear that's not working. Are you sure you have your frameWidth and frameHeight measured correctly?

Comment: Nevermind! My height on the frameHeight was wrong so the spritesheet was not loaded correctly! That solved my problem thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I've put a [Phaser3 example game](https://github.com/BdR76/Phaser3-example-game) on github which adds a Button prototype to Scene, and the button works similar to Phaser v2

```
// add a button to a scene
// similar to buttons in Phaser v2
Phaser.Scene.prototype.addButton = function(x, y, key, callback, callbackContext, overFrame, outFrame, downFrame, upFrame)
{
        // add a button
        var btn = this.add.sprite(x, y, key, outFrame).setInteractive();
        btn.on('pointerover', function (ptr, x, y) { this.setFrame(overFrame) } );
        btn.on('pointerout',  function (ptr)       { this.setFrame(outFrame) } );
        btn.on('pointerdown', function (ptr)       { this.setScale(0.9, 0.9) } );
        btn.on('pointerup', callback.bind(callbackContext));

        return btn;
};

// load sprite sheet
this.load.atlas('sprites', 'img/mysprites.png', 'img/mysprites.json');

// then use it like this
this.btnback = this.addButton(100, 100, 'sprites', this.myBtnCallBack, this, 'btn_back_hl', 'btn_back', 'btn_back_hl', 'btn_back');
```

Comment: Wow! Great way to bring back the button constructor from Phaser 2. Thanks